# Can't get a Stringbuffer to print

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to print out the odd numbers between 0 and 30 using threads but I can't seem to get the Stringbuffer that I'm trying to store my numbers into print.

```
public class THREAD extends Thread {
 public void run()
{
    for (int x=0; x<30; x++)
    {
     int y=-1;
     int n= y+2; 
    }
     StringBuffer numberslist = new StringBuffer(n);    
     System.out.println(numberslist);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    (new THREAD()).start();
}
}
```

Comment: I think this will not even compile since you haven't declared `n` used in `new StringBuffer(n)` anywhere.

Comment: n is constant: (-1) + 2 = 1 ? why use  loop then? just `System.out.println(1);`

Comment: You should not use `THREAD` as a class name, stick to the Java Camel Case conventions for classes and use a name which prints it purpose, like `BackgroundListPrinterThread`

Comment: "printing odd numbers" - see my answer's sample

Answer (score 1):

If this would compile (it does not as `int n` is only visible inide the loop), you would create an empty `StringBuffer()` of length 1<sup>*</sup> with the [`new StringBuffer(int capacity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer%28int%29) call. Then you print it. As it is empty (you have'nt used any `append(...)` on it) it will print an empty line.

If you actually want to add the string representation of an integer to a string buffer you would have to use one of:

```
StringBuffer numbers = new StringBuffer(""+n);
// String.valueOf(n) calls Integer.toString(n)
StringBuffer numbers = new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(n));
```

(which is however not the best idea as it startes with a matching length), or use the append variants:

```
StringBuffer numbers = new StringBuffer(); // default capacity
numbers.append(""+n);
numbers.append(Integer.toString(n));
```

(note that I also renamed the variable, as a buffer is not a list).

Printing the odd numbers would be like (however you can also skip the buffer completely and just print):

```
StringBuffer numbers = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 1; i < 30; i+=2) {
  if (i>1) numbers.append(','); // or space?
  numbers.append(Integer.toString(i));
}
System.out.println("odd numbers: " + numbers);
```

In all of the examples you can replace `StringBuffer` with the more modern `StringBuilder` - it wont alter the output but is faster. However it is even better to not store results in memory when you can stream them out:

```
System.out.print("odd numbers: "); // cursor stays on line
for (int i = 1; i < 30; i+=2) {
  if (i>1) System.out.print(",");
  System.out.print(Integer.toString(i));
}
System.out.println(); // next line
```

<sup>*</sup> The comments explain why n = 1: you calculate 30 times the result of `n = -1 + 2;`

Comment: Btw: `""+n` >> Integer.toString(n) >> String.valueOf(n): https://gist.github.com/ecki/399136f4fd59c1d110c1